# Error converting HttpRequest to HttpRequestBase for unit test

Tags: unit-testing

We are doing an upgrade from 8.2 to 10.2, and the code has a lot of unit tests. One element in a number of them involves the HttpRequestBegin pipeline, where there's an article about the code to use for Sitecore 9 here: https://www.andybutland.dev/2017/11/unit-testing-httprequestargs-with-sitecore-9.html. The relevant code that the blogger said worked was this:

```
public static HttpRequestArgs CreateHttpRequestArgs(string url)
{
    var httpRequest = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, url, string.Empty);
    var httpResponse = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
    var httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);
 
    var requestArgs = new HttpRequestArgs(new HttpContextWrapper(httpContext), HttpRequestType.End);
     
    // Reflection used to set the protected Url property
    var property = requestArgs.GetType().GetProperty("Url", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    property?.SetValue(requestArgs, new RequestUrl(httpRequest));
 
    return requestArgs;
}
```

We tried this out, but the second to last line `property?.SetValue(requestArgs, new RequestUrl(httpRequest));` gives an error that it can't convert HttpRequest to HttpRequestBase. We tried casts but it wouldn't go for that.

Has anyone had to do a unit test in Sitecore 10 in a similar fashion that has a code sample that works, or can point in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from `Sitecore 9` you can get rid of all those customizations at all. The article describes a hack how to set `httpRequest` via reflection. The new `HttpRequestBase` class is the [long-awaited absraction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontextbase?view=netframework-4.8.1) that makes all those hacks unnecessary. You can just mock it. See how `HttpRequestArgs` can be created in new Sitecore:

```
[Fact]
public void CreateHttpRequestArgs1()
{
    var args = new HttpRequestArgs(Substitute.For<HttpContextBase>());
    Assert.NotNull(args.HttpContext);
}
```

In combination with AutoFixture it can be even more elegant:

```
[Theory, AutoNSubstituteData]
public void CreateHttpRequestArgs(HttpRequestArgs args)
{
    Assert.NotNull(args.HttpContext);
}
```

**UPDATE**

Just in case you still want the code above to work, did you try to use `RequestWrapper`?

```
...
property?.SetValue(requestArgs, new RequestUrl(new HttpRequestWrapper(httpRequest)));
```